# Tumblr total posts stat - possible?

Tags: javascript, html, api, tumblr

I have a group Tumblr blog with 9 members. I am currently the main contributor on it and when I don't post I've noticed that the blog can at times go into a lull of inactivity. As an incentive for posting I've come up with an idea and I need your help in making it a reality.

I want to list the top contributors in a box on the index page, something like this:

**Author / Posts / Average notes per post**
john / 456 / 45.8
phil / 34 / 12.5

and so on.

I know my way around basic HTML and have no trouble in "installing" JS but not writing it. I've seen features for Tumblr blogs expand tenfold with API, however, I have no clue what this is.

Can somebody please tell me if this request is at all possible on Tumblr and if not what is API and how can I use it to better my blog?

Comment: I've managed to find a JS code that works out the average.
I'm going to attempt to work this into Tumblr API somehow.